# Error with controls and AbstractControls when building a form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have this form :

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
        points: new FormArray([
            new FormGroup({
                date: this.date,
                startTime: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
                endTime: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            }),
            new FormGroup({
                date: this.date,
                startTime: new FormControl(),
                endTime: new FormControl(),
            }),
            new FormGroup({
                date: this.date,
                startTime: new FormControl(),
                endTime: new FormControl(),
            })
        ]),
    });
```

When I submit I have this form :

```
for (const group of (this.myForm.get('points') as FormArray).controls) {
            console.log(group);
            if (group.controls.date !== null) {
                if (group.controls.date.value !== null) {
                    group.controls.startTime.setValue(
                        group.controls.date.value + ' ' + group.controls.startTime.value
                    );
                    group.controls.endTime.setValue(
                        group.controls.date.value + ' ' + group.controls.endTime.value
                    );
                    group.controls.date.setValue(group.controls.date.value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Works just fine but when I try to `ng build --prod` I have the error :
`Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'`. How can I access the controls of a FormGroup in a FormArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have to cast the group specifically to a FormGroup as such:

```
for (const group of (this.myForm.get("points") as FormArray).controls as FormGroup[]) {
```